# ffmpeg unicode file name not working

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi when I use arabic file name in the $video variable the ffmpeg is throwing the error:
Input/output error

the command is as follows:

```
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -ss $interval -vframes 1 -f image2 -s $size $temp_thumbnail_url";
```

english file names works great.

Comment: How are you running the command? In what environment/platform/language?

Comment: shell? The assignment above is not correct due to spacing... Also, what does the expanded command look like? i.e. with all the parameters expanded.

Comment: I don't have php environment on my local ... i am testing it directly on the server

Comment: $cmd = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i تست.flv -ss 5 -vframes 1 -f image2 -s 100x80 xx.jpeg";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a direct solution to this problem but I found a workaround. I didn't pass the file name from the post:

```
($_FILES['theFile']['name'])
```

Because it contains Arabic character, instead I used the temporary file generated:

```
($_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'])
```

and created the thumbnail from the temporary file using ffmpeg.